Sci-fi western, I read in the 80's about a guy who would have targeting reticles in his eyes when using a special set of blasters
While I was on board the USS Midway, I read this book about a guy whose father had put sensors in his hands. Targeting reticles would appear in his vision, and time would also slowdown when he would use a special set of blasters. His father was a space explorer and had gone missing, he set out to look for him. This guys father also designed a special suit and blasters.
The main character tried using other blasters but the reticles would not align causing him to miss his target. He eventually finds his father's special suit and blasters. He travels to this planet with translucent type dinosaurs that communicate telepathically. This book made such an impact on me, I been looking for it for the last 30+ years.

Everything but the dinosaurs sounds really familiar... Gonna have to let this one percolate for a while.

Thought this was going to be David Drake's The General series, but no, definitely not.
